# What does 'one narrative for all' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage

It's in a book and a character goes like:

> "That comes as no surprise. They strike me as thick as pigshit; one narrative for all.But what exactly in this instance don’t they understand?"

Here,what does it means by *"one narrative for all'*?

Comment: They all believe the same thing, with no dissension.

Comment: They're singing from the same hymnsheet, though 'fools seldom differ' has the more relevant connotation here.